# Porque al marcar un icono como favorito se marcan todos a la vez?

Tags: flutter

Si alguien tiene un titulo mejor para la pregunta bien pueda editarla. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver en la imagen el problema es que cuando marco un icono como favorito los demas tambien lo hacen, y la verdad no se como lograr para que cada marcador sea independiente.
estoy manejando los estados con provider. aqui el modelo

```
class HeartIconState with ChangeNotifier {
  Icon _hearticon = const Icon(
    Icons.favorite_border,
  );
  Icon get hearticon => _hearticon;

  void changeHeart() {
    if (_hearticon.icon == Icons.favorite_border) {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite,
      );
    } else {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite_border,
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set hearticon(Icon value) {
    _hearticon = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

y aqui la forma en que los llamo.

```
Align(
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
child: IconButton(
icon: Heart.hearticon,
onPressed: Heart.changeHeart,
color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
```

tambien pondre toda la tarjeta por si de pronto alguien le interesa.

```
Card(
        elevation: 5.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
        child: InkWell(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 200.0,
            height: 250.0,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 155.0,
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        imageUrl: url,
                        placeholder: (context, urlImage) =>
                            Container(color: Colors.grey),
                        errorWidget: (context, urlImage, error) =>
                            Center(child: Container(color: Colors.grey)))),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ubicacion != ""
                            ? Text(ubicacion,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                                maxLines: 1)
                            : Container(),
                        titulo != ""
                            ? Text(titulo,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                maxLines: 2)
                            : Container(),
                        precio != ""
                            ? Text(precio,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                maxLines: 1)
                            : Container(),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Heart.hearticon,
                            onPressed: Heart.changeHeart,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que estás usando un único provider para todas las tarjetas. Aquí tienes dos opciones, o inyectado un provider en cada tarjeta, de forma que cada tarjeta tenga su propio provider o en un único provider tienes una lista con todos los elementos necesarios. Uno por tarjeta. Cuando hagas onTap, le pasas el index de la tarjeta que debe modificarse y en el provider modificas el elemento correspondiente

Comment: la primera opcion no parece nada eficiente seria repetir muchas lineas. la segunda llama mas la atencion. no podrias porfavor agregarla como respuesta?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que te ponga un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: si A migo pero con el gestor provider que es con el que esta formulada la pregunta. no he podido solucionarlo

Comment: No uso provider. Dale una vuelta a lo que te he comentado. No es difícil de implementar.